# Function argument list of parameters

Tags: arguments

I have a function like:

```
fn[x_, a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] := a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4
```

I would like to think of the a,b,c,d,e as parameters. I usually fix them to some constants,
and continue working with the variable x, like so,

```
Table[fn[x,0,1,2,3,4],{x,0,10}]
```

To avoid cluttering, I would like to define the a,b,c,d,e in a list and feed it into the function like so:

```
para = {0,1,2,3,4};
Table[fn[x,para],{x,0,10}]
```

Of course, this does not work because the format of the arguments is not right, but I don't know how to make it work?

Comment: `fn[x_, {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_}] := a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4` ?

Comment: It might make more sense to define the function as `fn[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_}][x_] := ...`, so you can call it as `fn[para][x]`. This makes the difference between the parameters and the free variable more obvious and you my even do `myfun = fn[para]; myfun[x]` to define the function for specific parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user Sjoerd Smit commented, one can define the function as

```
fn[{a_,b_,c_,d_,e_}][x_] := a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4
```

This nicely separates parameters and variables. This also allows
defining the function for specific parameters. E.g.

```
para = {0,1,2,3,4};    
fnFixedpara[x_] := fn[para][x]
```

Usage example:

```
Table[fn[para][x],{x,0,10}]
Table[fnFixedpara[x],{x,0,10}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) and [`Apply`(`@@`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)

With `fn` in OP and

```
params = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Then

```
fn[2, Sequence @@ params]
```

> ```
> 98
> ```

and

```
Table[fn[x, Sequence @@ params], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
> {0, 10, 98, 426, 1252, 2930, 5910, 10738, 18056, 28602, 43210}
> ```

Hope this helps.